# Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, email, laravel, outlook

I can send my emails in localhost flawlessly. but ever since I uploaded my program into a hosting site I get this error

> Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

I also updated the `.env` file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=email@outlook.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=123456789
```

works in localhost but not in the hosting site.

i am using laravel 5

Comment: What is this program you have uploaded? What steps have you taken? Where does the error occur? If we have more information it will be easier to help you.

Comment: What hosting company are you using? More likely this is because your hosting company blocks outgoing traffic on 587.

Comment: @silverskin 
its a personal website. this page acts as contact us page. i didn't touch the mail.php anymore because it is working well in my localhost. so i assumed that it will do its job ones i've uploaded it.

Comment: @Blaatpraat 
hostinger. i'm just using free domain and hosting. i am just testing it if it will work IRL.

i am using my personal e-mail to receive the message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like the smtp was blocked for hostinger free users.

http://www.hostinger.ph/forum/news-and-announcements/229-email-service-updates-1.html

Comment: @Primercore its always good practice to mark the answer which worked for you as an accepted answer. This way other users will have more confidence using this solution. I have noted you lately not marking some of your working answer as accepted. And you can also accept your own answer. Thanks for contributions to community.

Answer (score 14):

I ran through this error so many times for some reasons.

When see this error,

> Expected response code 250 but got code “”, with message “”

## Please **triple** check your email password.

**Note :**
Test your credentals first on a phone app or log-in into the mail site.
If pass, you may update in your `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=dev.bheng@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
```

---

If you know for **sure** that your password is correct.

Check to make sure your Gmail or Yahoo Mail allow app log-in.

**Example**

`Yahoo`

[image]

Answer (score 11):

we solved this problem by clearing the Laravel's configuration cache

`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Fixed it for us.

Comment: nice to hear it. Whenever i got stuck with laravel config problems i imediatly run `composer dump autoload` and `php artisan config:cache`, their are the best chances you have to start a problem solving on laravel.

Comment: As it turned out, it was not a permanent fix.  Ultimately I created a new Sendgrid account for that client which fixed issue - how I have no clue, but it did.

Comment: have you checked your Sendgrid's send limits? Based on what your are describing the problem seems to be related to Sendgrid not with Laravel or PHP.

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me, 'if you are using GMAIL'

1. Go to 'My Accounts'
2. Go to 'Sign-in & security'
3. Scroll down to 'Allow less secure apps'
4. Switch #3 to ON

After doing this and if you just recently set up your email configurations on laravel and still doesn't work, try running:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a working laravel swiftmailer using google server. Here my steps:

1. I visited the link
   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and turned
   on less secure apps.
2. I edited .env file as like below:

   > MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   >
   > MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
   >
   > MAIL_PORT=587
   >
   > MAIL_USERNAME=username   //i.e. username@gmail.com
   >
   > MAIL_PASSWORD=password //Gmail accounts password
   >
   > MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Edit username and password with your own.

3. In my controller, I wrote the following code:

   > $rawData = request::all();
   >
   > Mail::queue('program.meeting.emailInvite', $rawData, function($message) use ($rawData)
   >
   > {
   >
   > $message->from('info@echosofts.com', 'Echosofts')->to(array_map('trim', explode(',', $rawData['all_email_id'])))->subject($rawData['mail_title']);
   >
   > });

Then email was working fine except the sender email ID was my google account (username@gmail.com) instead of info@echosofts.com.

4. To overcome the sender email changing problem, I visited my google account and did the following:

"Setting icon"-> Settings -> Accounts and Import->Send mail as->Add another email address your own.

> The following settings depends on your configuration.

```
    Email address: info@echosofts.com
    SMTP server: mail.echosofts.com
    Username: info@echosofts.com
    password:**********
    Port:25
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - I get this error when sending a email with an empty string in the `to` field.

Answer (score 0):

in "mautic" (CRM), if you mail to a large amount of contacts, like more than 10k this occurs. The real reason is mostly a wrong configuration in php settings. For example:

max_input_time = 60

Will only let your server run the script for 60 seconds, try a higher value.

PHP configuration depends on your server and its installed software, mostly configured by htaccess or php.ini file.