# vagrant laravel 5.3 gmail Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, laravel-5.3

There are many post regarding this problem but none of them seems to fix my problem.
I'm trying to send email using gmail account from my local vagrant box.
My mail config:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => 'myaccount@gmail.com',
    'name' => 'Example',
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

`.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myaccount@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=16digit_gmail_app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My code:

```
\Mail::send('email.order',[], function($message) {
    $message->to('other_email@email.com', 'John Smith')
    $message->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

In my gmail account I acctivated 2-Step Verification and I created a app password (`select app -> mail`, `select device -> Other/myLocalDomain`.

When I try to send email I get `Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""`
I'm probably missing something here but I can't figure what.

Comment: I think you should try code from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message)