# Laravel 5.1 - Swift_TransportException - cant send emails

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, laravel-5, sendgrid

1. at .env file I have this code:

   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

   ```
   MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net

   MAIL_PORT=587

   MAIL_USERNAME=azure_edhjjjjj67781b06b18228961b@azure.com

   MAIL_PASSWORD=hggahsd666

   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
   ```

and I get this screen:

[image]

I also try:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
    MAIL_PORT=465
    MAIL_USERNAME=azure_edhjjjjj67781b06b18228961b@azure.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=hggahsd666
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

but dont works again...

I also try to change settings into config/mail.php to be the same as on .env file but dont work and at the end I try command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Is possible problem cause redirection to secure domain https://asdasd.com/sendEmail ?

Comment: I also try with     MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null but again dont work

Comment: no, offcource :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep mail.php like this way

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'hello@example.com',
        'name' => 'Example',
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

Then cross check all your credentials in .env file, If still not work then go to your email account and change app settings to allow less secure apps

Comment: Also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message ... It seems your question is repeated . check these solutions you will get solutions for this.