# Unable to send email using swiftmailer library. Getting Expected response code 250 but got code "550". How to fix this?

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

My laravel application isn't working with mijn domain smtp mail.

[SMTP credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1svsS.png)

These are the credentials for my smtp mail.
This is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.transip.email
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@schouwenduivelandinbeeld.nl
MAIL_PASSWORD=Hallootjes123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I get this error:

[The error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1svsS.png)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry SMTP img isn't right:

Comment: Server: smtp.transip.email

Comment: port: 465 and username: email address password: email password

Comment: have you tried username without @schouwenduivelandinbeeld.nl

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message

Comment: I think you should hide the real credentials off your email.

Comment: Check this one [Expected response code 250 but got code “”, with message “”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message)

Comment: same datas update in config/mail.php

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I found the porblem, i forgot to specify the MAIL_FROM_ADRESS and the MAIL_FORM_NAME in my .env file.