# Laravel 5.4: Swift_TransportException trying to send notification with scheduled command

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send a notification about upcoming events to relevant users.

I'm testing locally on Homestead and use mailtrap SMTP to test emails. I've created a scheduler that runs a console command. The command should send a notification + email with Laravel's `notify` facade.

```
$user->notify(new \App\Notifications\Event($event, user));
```

Problem is, I get an `Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""` error. The notification is sent normally, but no email is sent. When I run the exact same notification through a controller, I have no issues, but this has something to do with either the command or the scheduler.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov No. As I said, everything works when I run the notification through the controller, meaning that all my settings are correct. I also test this exclusively on localhost.