# Laravel 5 Mail::raw works in tinker but doesn't in app

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I've a very strange issue sending SMTP email from Laravel

```
Mail::raw('Email body', function ($message) use ($filename) {
            $message->from('sender@email.com', 'Ordini')
              ->to('user@email.com')
              ->subject('subject')
              ->attach(storage_path($filename));
        });
```

This code actually **works** within server's **tinker** environment but it doesn't when it's executed within **controller**.

I've double checked .env and config/mail.php, everything is fine

The server mail is my client's smtp mail server

I also tried without any attachment

The response is "**Expected response code 250 but got an empty response**"

I can't figure out why it works in tinker while it doesn't in app. What's the difference?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Please put your code in a try-catch block and check if it is throwing some error.

Comment: Yes, the code is actually inside a try-catch block. The response is from $e->getMessage();

Thanks

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Already tried. It didn't help. Thanks

Comment: Is your gmail follows two step authentication or do not allow third party unsecure apps

Comment: It might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133301/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message

Comment: It's not a gmail service, but my client's local smtp server. Anyway, why it works from tinker? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your you have not enabled two step authentication on your gmail and you have allowed less secured apps on your google account 
After Checking all that Just try to run command

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Make sure your env file contain these info

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_email
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And then

Instead of your mail code code try like this

```
        Mail::raw('Email body', function ($message) use ($filename) {
            $message->from('sender@email.com', 'Ordini');
            $message->to('user@email.com');
            $message->subject('subject');
            $message->attach(storage_path($filename));
        });
```

Check in the config/mail.php 
If it is getting every thing from env or not if not make changes in config file

Comment: I'm not using gmail but my client's local smtp mail server. I tried your code and it didn't work. Everything is ok in env e config (it works in tinker btw). Thanks a lot